# Problems using static MemcachedClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, memcached

I am using Memcached to store data for fast access. I have read that creating MemcachedClient is costly and saw an usage of MemcachedClient as static (See : [link](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=TsEkbkBWKpAC&pg=PA173&lpg=PA173&dq=using%20static%20memcachedclient&source=bl&ots=6T6NzLWdqZ&sig=ux5EFUNKh-WdgyWBbWb5tfYFps4&hl=tr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZgfqC9ebPAhVJORQKHehiA0AQ6AEISDAF#v=onepage&q=using%20static%20memcachedclient&f=false))

So I used Singleton pattern for my Client as :

```
public class CommonObjectsCache
{
    private static CommonObjectsCache _cache;
    private static MemcachedClient _client;

    public static MemcachedClient Client
    {
        get
        {
            if (_client == null)
                _client = new MemcachedClient();

            return _client;
        }
        private set
        {
            _client = value;
        }
    }

    private CommonObjectsCache()
    {
        _client = new MemcachedClient();
    }

    public static CommonObjectsCache Cache
    {
        get
        {
            if (_cache == null)
                _cache = new CommonObjectsCache();

            return _cache;
        }
    }
}
```

In my DAL I am using them as follows :

```
    public static List<Item1> AllItem1s
    {
        get
        {
            if (CommonObjectsCache.Client.Get<List<Item1>>("AllItem1s") == null)
                RefreshItem1Cache();

            return CommonObjectsCache.Client.Get<List<Item1>>("AllItem1s");
        }
        private set
        {
            CommonObjectsCache.Client.Store(StoreMode.Set, "AllItem1s", value);
        }
    }
    public static List<Item2> AllItem2s
    {
        get {  // Same as above }
        private set { // Same as above }
    }
    public static List<Item3> AllItem3s
    {
        get {  // Same as above }
        private set { // Same as above }
    }
    public static List<Item4> AllItem4s
    {
        get {  // Same as above }
        private set { // Same as above }

    }
```

And fill them as :

```
public static void RefreshItem1Cache()
{
    List<Item1> items = (from i ctx.Item1
                        select i).ToList();
    AllItem1s = items;
}
```

In my DAL code I have a method like :

```
public static MyModel GetMyModel(int? id)
{
    // I use AllItem1s here.
}
```

When I run the code it sometimes says that `AllItem1s.Count == 0`, but when I put a breakpoint and diagnose that value in AllItem1s, I see that it is filled. So, I updated the code as follows to check if I am doing wrong :

```
public static MyModel GetMyModel(int? id)
{
    if (AllItem1s == null || AllItem1s.Count == 0 || AllItem2s == null || AllItem2s.Count == 0 || AllItem3s == null || AllItem3s.Count == 0 || AllItem4s == null || AllItem4s.Count == 0)
    {
        string msg = "Error!!!!!";
    }
    // I use AllItem1s here.
}
```

And surprisingly enough, the code falls to `string msg = "Error!!!!!";` block!!!

But when I put a breakpoint inside the `if` block and watch for the `Count` property of each collection I see that thay have numbers.

So I came to a conclusion that there is a race condition while fetching `AllItemXs` property. When it checks for the condition at least one of them has not been properly set (*which does not make sense, since they are on the same thread and getter of the property can not return empty collection*).

Can anybody explain why this happens and how to overcome with this isue?

Comment: How does the RefreshItem1Cache(); method look like? Is CommonObjectsCache.Client setter used somewhere? Where is RefreshGroupCache() used?

Comment: Can you show the code of `SearchItem1s`?

Comment: Those are plain EF calls. I have updated the code.

Comment: So you never actually use `CommonObjectsCache.Cache`?

Answer (score 2):

Your singleton implementation is not thread-safe.
Imagine, that two(or more) threads hit null check at the same time: both(all) threads will initialize their own instance of CommonObjectsCache.

You can wrap null check and initialization of instance with lock statement or use double-check locking pattern.

Just google for thread-safe singleton implementation in C#.